# Pyside Qt designer output file connecting slots issue

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, pyside, pyqt5

I have created a dialog using QT Designer and converted to Python using pyside-uic

The program is a simple button as I am currently learning pyside, I want to connect the button to a function called 'buttonpushed' just to print "button pushed" when the button is clicked however despite following online tutorials my button does not work.

This error does not occur when I simply code in the button however when i use the designer and it becomes a dialog I can't get it to work.

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class Ui_Dialog(object):
def setupUi(self, Dialog):
    Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
    Dialog.resize(400, 300)
    self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(Dialog)
    self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 120, 71, 23))
    self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

    self.retranslateUi(Dialog)

    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)


def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
    Dialog.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "Dialog", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.pushButton.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "PushButton", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))


def buttonpushed(self):
    print 'buttonpushed'


if __name__ == "__main__":
import sys
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
Dialog = QtGui.QDialog()
ui = Ui_Dialog()
ui.setupUi(Dialog)
Dialog.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have to do is connect the signal with the desired function, you can do it inside or outside the class.

```
{yourobject}.{object signal}.connect({your slot})
```

**Code:**

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(400, 300)
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 120, 71, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)

        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.buttonpushed)



    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "Dialog", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "PushButton", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))


    def buttonpushed(self):
        print('buttonpushed')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtGui.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Another Solution:**

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(400, 300)
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 120, 71, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)

        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)



    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "Dialog", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "PushButton", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))


    def buttonpushed(self):
        print('buttonpushed')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtGui.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(ui.buttonpushed)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Great, this works perfectly, is there any way to connect it from outside the Ui_Dialog class?

Comment: @WilliamHamilton Update my answer, if it helps you mark it as correct please.